# Some items are not removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, items

I'm have a problem with `remove()`. I have to read a string and it convert to a list, then this list I must remove item `""`, but the last items are not removed.
I show you the code:

```
def telegrama(texto):
    c_aux = texto.split(" ")
    print(c_aux)

    for i in c_aux:
         if i == "":
         c_aux.remove(i)
    print(c_aux)

texto = "  Llego mañana alrededor del mediodía "

telegrama(texto)
```

I show the result

[image]

Comment: You can use `split` with no arguments to get this behavior.  Try `texto.split()`.

Comment: You shouldn't change a list while iterating it, or weird stuff like this happens.

Comment: By the way, it's a good practice to not paste screenshots of your code.

Comment: Why isn't the last ' ' being removed?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh A question. How did you do to edit the code so well? I always get it wrong when I try to hit Stack. Because I can not find a way to pay for it with the python formats

Comment: @Calvin Have you read the help page on formatting? https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thaks bro for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) first:

```
c_aux = texto.strip().split(" ")
```

`str.strip()` returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing whitespace removed.

If you need to just remove from the left or right, you can use `lstrip()` or `rstrip()` respectively.

Comment: I didn't know this function, with this I could avoid 'for'. Thank you bro.